# Trigger DAG from google cloud function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-composer

I have been trying to execute a DAG in Cloud Composer (**composer-1.8.1-airflow-1.10.3**) when a file arrives at a GCS bucket based on the cloud [composer documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/triggering-with-gcf) with Cloud Function in Python

I haven't been able to make it work, every time it triggers, the function returns  this message to the log

```
Exception: Bad response from application: 400 / {'Date': 'Mon, 30 Dec 2019 18:07:02 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'Content-Length': '192', 'Server': 'gunicorn/19.9.0', 'Via': '1.1 google', 'Alt-Svc': 'quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43",h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000'} / '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">\n<title>400 Bad Request</title>\n<h1>Bad Request</h1>\n<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>\n'
```

The request URL s¡generate and the open id token seems correct
The error is raised in the last part of the code

```
resp = requests.request(
    method, url,
    headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(
        google_open_id_connect_token)}, **kwargs)
if resp.status_code == 403:
    raise Exception('Service account {} does not have permission to '
                    'access the IAP-protected application.'.format(
                        signer_email))
elif resp.status_code != 200:
    raise Exception(
        'Bad response from application: {!r} / {!r} / {!r}'.format(
            resp.status_code, resp.headers, resp.text))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error code [*400 Bad Request*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1) reflected in the initial question more often corresponds to the client side problem, indeed the input parameters for DAG triggering should be inspected as a first, the function that invokes [IAP](https://cloud.google.com/iap/) call in the code [example](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/triggering-with-gcf#creating_your_function):

```
def make_iap_request(url, client_id, method='GET', **kwargs)
```

Ensure, that you have applied dependencies required to run against IAP protected URL via `requirements.txt` file.

Do not forget to verify the essential arguments that you pass to this function:

> url: The Identity-Aware Proxy-protected URL to fetch.
>
> client_id: The client ID used by Identity-Aware Proxy.

So far I haven't found even better hand on experience about triggering the DAG then explained by [@Jacob Ferriero](https://medium.com/@jtferriero) in his great [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/using-airflow-experimental-rest-api-on-google-cloud-platform-cloud-composer-and-iap-9bd0260f095a).

Comment: Thanks, I solved my problem, there was an issue with the
`requests.request(
        method, url,
        headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(
            google_open_id_connect_token)}, **kwargs)` of the make_iap_request function. I didn't need any param for the call to airflow, so I wasn't using any kwarg. It seems that JSON argument it's needed to call the function